# Node.js app TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object

Tags: javascript, node-modules

I'm trying to create a folder view/circle where Im gonna be able to render the array  but when I do localhost:3001/views/circle is not loading anything, instead I get the error on the title....................................................................................................................

```
//-------I added this part in the code as you can see bellow this code-------
//const path = require("path");

//app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
//app.set("view engine", "ejs");
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const express = require('express')
const path = require("path");
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()


// view engine setup
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(cors())

const circles = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Twitter',
        image: 'img/twitter.jpg',
        color: '#aa2b31',
        size: 3
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Facebook',
        image: 'img/facebook.jpg',
        color: '#63e184',
        size: 1
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Skype',
        image: 'img/skype.png',
        color: '#033d49',
        size: 2
    },
]



app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const help = `

    `

    res.send(help)
  })

app.get('/circles', (req, res) => {
    res.render(circles)
})

app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on port 3001')
})

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Does the error message include a line number?

Comment: Try console logging `__dirname`. My hunch is it's undefined.

Comment: yeah.   at validateString (internal/validators.js:125:11)
    at extname (path.js:830:5)
    at new View (C:\Users\BrunoAlvesdaSilva\Downloads\vianuvem-frontend\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:56:14)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\BrunoAlvesdaSilva\Downloads\vianuvem-frontend\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\BrunoAlvesdaSilva\Downloads\vianuvem-frontend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
    at app.get (C:\Users\BrunoAlvesdaSilva\Downloads\vianuvem-frontend\server.js:49:9)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not to any help in this particular case, but it might be to someone who searches on this error. I got this because I had placed the routes in incorrect order. My `/:id` path caught the post request before it got to where it was supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `set` with `use`:

from

```
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
```

to

```
app.use("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
```